# Vertical alignment of arrow between images

Tags: graphics, vertical-alignment, arrows

I'm struggling with template given for my article. I've got four images and I'd like to place right arrow between them.

[image: Problem]

Problem is that arrows should be in the middle instead of at the bottom.

```
\Teaser{
    \TeaserImage{orig.png}
    \Rightarrow
    \TeaserImage{grid.png}
    \Rightarrow
    \TeaserImage{map.png}
    \Rightarrow
    \TeaserImage{predictions.png}
}
```

Commands `Teaser` and `TeaserImage` are defined in template like so

```
\newcommand{\Teaser}[1]{\global\HaveTeasertrue\def\@Teaser{#1}}
\newcommand{\TeaserImage}[1]{\includegraphics[height=1in]{#1}}
```

I've tried to use `vspace`, but without any luck.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please -- as usual here -- make your code snippet compilable!

Comment: Try to use `\vcenter{\hbox{...}}`. It is hard to test or be more detailed since you do not provide a complete code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=50pt]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx,amssymb}
%\newcommand{\Teaser}[1]{\global\HaveTeasertrue\def\@Teaser{#1}}
\newcommand{\TeaserImage}[1]{\raisebox{%
  .5\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox-\dp\strutbox}{%
  \includegraphics[height=1in]{#1}}}
\begin{document}
$%\Teaser{
    \TeaserImage{example-image}
    \Rightarrow
    \TeaserImage{example-image-a}
    \Rightarrow
    \TeaserImage{example-image-b}
    \Rightarrow
    \TeaserImage{example-image-c}
$%}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Steven - this did the job well. Also is there any other way without modification of the template (`TeaserImage`)?

Comment: @FilipKočica You can redefine `\includegraphics`, but I don't recommend it. You could modify the template by one letter, capitalizing `\includegraphics` to `\Includegraphics`, and define the latter to perform the `\raisebox` accordingly.

Comment: @FilipKočica after loading the template, you could `\let\svTeaserImage\TeaserImage
\renewcommand{\TeaserImage}[1]{\raisebox{.5\dimexpr-\height+\ht\strutbox-\dp\strutbox}{\svTeaserImage{#1}}}`

Comment: Thanks @Steven, that's very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Just spelling out my comment.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\newcommand{\TeaserImage}[1]{\vcenter{\hbox{\includegraphics[height=1in]{#1}}}}
\begin{document}
$\TeaserImage{example-image-duck}
    \Rightarrow
    \TeaserImage{example-image-duck}
    \Rightarrow
    \TeaserImage{example-image-duck}
    \Rightarrow
    \TeaserImage{example-image-duck}$
\end{document}
```

[image]